Google Cloud Metrics for Google Cloud Language API
In my project I use Google Cloud Language API for natural language processing. That API has usage quotas:

I'd like to plot this quota usage eg. on Grafana charts, and in order to do that I need to read corresponding metrics using Google Cloud Monitoring API, I guess.
Fetching limits seems easy, using this PromQL:
sum(avg_over_time(
    serviceruntime_googleapis_com:quota_limit{
        monitored_resource="consumer_quota",
        quota_metric="language.googleapis.com/default_requests",
        limit_name="DefaultRequestsPerDayPerProject"}
    [${__interval}]))

In order to fetch actual quota usage, not just the limits, quota/allocation/usage metric should be used, but that does not seem to work:
sum(avg_over_time(
    serviceruntime_googleapis_com:quota_allocation_usage{
        monitored_resource="consumer_quota",
        quota_metric="language.googleapis.com/default_requests",
        limit_name="DefaultRequestsPerDayPerProject"
    }[${__interval}]))


No data is available for the selected time frame.


And if I try to select that in Metrics Explorer I get

Filter contains labels not supported for the selected metric

error message:

The docs mention that "not all services support quota metrics in Cloud Monitoring", but Language API is not explicitly mentioned, neither as supported nor unsupported. But I would find it strange if quota limits would be supported, whereas actual quota usage not.

Check quota metric support
Not all services support quota metrics in Cloud Monitoring. To see
applicable quota metrics for supported services, select Consumer Quota
as the resource type when building a chart or creating an alerting
policy. Services that don't support quota metrics aren't displayed.

Common services that support quota metrics include Compute Engine,    Dataflow, Spanner, Pub/Sub, Cloud Vision, Speech-to-Text, Cloud
Monitoring, and Cloud Logging.

Common services that don't support quota metrics include App Engine and Cloud SQL.



